# Data import from excel breaking up the values

Tags: python, excel

Taking data from an excel spreadsheet I get my fourth column to look like

```
fourth_column = [32.86667, 34.08333, 39.0, 36.63333, -13.2, 30.8, 14.3]
```

these are all values for latitude and I get similar values for longitude. I wondered if there was an easy way for running them each separately through my code one after the other, setting latitude to equal something which will take each value in turn.

Answer (score 0):

```
for value in fourth_column:
    do_something(value)
```